# How to set a fixed IP for a VirtualBox machine to make it appears identical on different computers

Tags: network-programming, ip, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware

I have an Ubuntu VM (with a Varnish Cache) running in VirtualBox on my local computer. When I'm at home the ip address of my computer is 192.168.178.34. I use the network bridge to connect the VM with my computer. The ip of the VM is then 192.168.178.38. That allows me to reach the cache-server e.g. like that: http://192.168.178.38:6081/index.html

The problem is, i want that this URI is static. My goal is to share the vm with somebody and make a documentation about how to use the cache-server. Therefore it would be great if the ip adress would be always the same, even if the vm will be started in a VirtualBox on a different computer.

Is there a way to set a fixed ip address for the vm, regardless of the host computer?

Thanks a lot!

martin.martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a host-only network adapter, which uses the subnet 192.168.56.0/24 by default. Inside the VM, you can set a static IP address.

Comment: What if my local computer gets the ip address 172.16.172.144. That happens for example if i'm at work with my laptop. In this case the subnet 192.168.56.0/24 would not fit, right?

Comment: The host-only network is completely independent of other network connections on your machine, as it works like a separate network card. Its subnet will not change, unless you change it manually.

Comment: Thanks for that! I will try it in another network soon.